# Issue when saving the webpage as image in asp.net c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing an issue regarding saving the whole webpage as image. I have a web application and all the controls used are 'user controls'. I have one page in my application and using that I grab the webpage image and saving to one folder in the solution. i got the image but the issue is the height of the image is not correct . Ie: the page height that I am receiving is not correct. When I debug , it shows 0px as height for the page.

My code is as follows:

```
    protected void GetThumbnailWorker()
    {
        using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            //browser.ClientSize = new Size(_width, _height);
            //browser.ClientSize = new Size(960,2000);
            browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.Navigate(_url); 


        // Wait for control to load page
        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            Application.DoEvents();

        // Render browser content to bitmap
        int imgaewidth = 0;
        int imageheight=0;
        imgaewidth=browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        imageheight=browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;


        if (imageheight <100)
        {
            imageheight = 1500;
        }
        if (imgaewidth == 0)
        {
            imgaewidth = 964;
        }
         browser.ClientSize = new Size(imgaewidth, imageheight);
        _bmp = new Bitmap(imgaewidth, imageheight);
         browser.DrawToBitmap(_bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0,
         imgaewidth, imageheight));

    }
}
```

I set the image height to 1500 due to this problem.

Can any one help me?

Updating the code:

```
public static Bitmap GetThumbnail(string url, int width, int height,
  int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight)
{
    WebsiteThumbnail thumbnail = new WebsiteThumbnail(url, width, height,
      thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
    return thumbnail.GetThumbnail();
}

/// <summary>
/// Protected constructor
/// </summary>
protected WebsiteThumbnail(string url, int width, int height,
  int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight)
{
    _url = url;
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _thumbWidth = thumbWidth;
    _thumbHeight = thumbHeight;
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a thumbnail for the current member values
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Thumbnail bitmap</returns>
protected Bitmap GetThumbnail()
{
    // WebBrowser is an ActiveX control that must be run in a
    // single-threaded apartment so create a thread to create the
    // control and generate the thumbnail
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetThumbnailWorker));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
    return _bmp.GetThumbnailImage(_thumbWidth, _thumbHeight,
      null, IntPtr.Zero) as Bitmap;
}
```

Comment: When are you calling this in the lifecycle? As a side note, your method naming of `Get...` is misleading, it doesn't return anything, so isn't "getting" anything. It's more of a `Do...`.

Comment: i updated the code ...please check it

Comment: It still makes no sense... but does shine other light: you're aware that threading in an ASP.NET/web environment is generally a bad/terrible idea, right?

Comment: yes..but it works for all other sites...!?

Comment: No, I can't think of a single web system that would have threading "work", at least not as expected every time, that's the point.

Comment: ok. so is there any other solution